# Increasing shadow in Blender Octane Edition?

Tags: materials, shadows, octane-render-engine

I'm using a Black Body Emission material on a plane as my light. Instead of casting harsher shadows it just lightens up where the light hits (I guess that's how light works). But how do I increase the shadow cast instead - i.e. make the shadow darker?

[image: My current setup emphasizing where I need more shadow]